# How to get a direct link to a downloadable file (for use with wget or cURL) that's normally downloaded via Javascript in a web browser

Tags: wget, download

A web site presents an xhtml page with a Download  clickable button. When clicked from the web page I get the .zip file. Instead of Browser - I'm try to automate the download using wget --referrer. For wget I need to the Download link. I have used Live HTTP Headers to capture the RR traffic - looks to me the server is throwing a JSF/PrimeFace page with Input as Hidden and does provide the link or path to the file. Here is what got from the capture:

```
</div><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="-3398716848402376611:2833976163771474925" autocomplete="off" />
```

I readup on a similar issue responses - in particular from user "hhaamu" - where he did not elaborate how he detected the hidden download link.

Answer (score 1):

Open the Network tab using the Developer Tools in Firefox. The Network tab shows resources that Firefox requests.  If you click the button that initiates the download, you should see the file resource appear in the Network tab.  From there you can grab the URL of the file resource by right-clicking it and then you can feed that URL to wget.

Answer (score 0):

Download it manually, then go to Downloads in your browser (ex. Show All Downloads in Firefox). Then you should be able to copy the resource link in the right-click pop-up menu.